# Why is this showing as a syntax error on my variable for a requests.get?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, syntax-error

I get this error:

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 4)pylint(syntax-error)
```

Invalid syntax on result on the fourth line.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get(https://www.google.com/)

result.status_code == requests.codes.ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Before all, you should consider using a real IDE to write your code (like [Eclipse/Pydev](http://www.pydev.org/), [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) or [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)), it would help you avoiding those kind of mistakes.

You are missing the quotes around your URL:

```
result = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: Simple, but completely missed it, thank you! I'm using VSCode but it didn't highlight it

Comment: Ah yes, I just tried with vscode, no error highlighted... I personnaly prefer the use of Eclipse and pydev, the python integration is just wonderful and an error like that is quickly indentified.

Comment: I'm just starting out so have no loyalty to VSCode, I'll have a look at some others, thanks for your help.